# Why is this Markov Property a consequence of the one of Brownian Motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process

For any $x \neq 0$ let $P^x$ be the distribution of Brownian Motion started at $x$. Then $(P^x)$ is a collection of probability measures on the space of cadlag functions denoted by $\Omega$.

For any $t>0$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ we can define $X(t)(\omega) = \omega(t)$ and this gives a stochastic process.

Also, for any $T>0$ let $\theta_T(\omega)(t) = \omega(T+t)$ be the time-shifted path.

I am trying to understand why this process satisfies the following Markov property:
For all $x \neq 0$, $T\ge 0$ and $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded and measurable we have:

$$\mathbb{E}^{P^{x}}[f(\theta_T(\omega))|\sigma(X_t)_{t \le T}] = \mathbb{E}^{P^{X_T}}[f]$$

I do know the Markov property of Brownian Motion, i.e. that for any $T>0$ the process $B_{T+t} - B_{T}$ is a Brownian Motion independent of $\sigma(B_t)_{t \le T}$, under the measure $P^0$ on $\Omega$.

But this statement seems a lot more abstract and I am struggling to see how it is a consequence of the Markov Property of Brownian Motion.

Comment: Look at Theorem 7.2.1 on page 360 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf).

Comment: @d.k.o Thanks, but the lecture notes prove the Markov Property which I already know to be true. So is there an easier way for me to see this? I will add what exactly I do understand in the question